# Swift: Why does "Pop Up Button" throw NSInternalInconsistencyException?

Tags: swift, button, interface-builder, ios15, nspopupbutton

I created a "Pop Up Button" following the WWDC video here:

["Build interfaces with style"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qapea.png)
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10196/?time=602

After adding the pop up button like shown in the video, I created an IBAction function like this:

```
@IBAction func onLanguageSelected(_ sender: Any?) {
    print("menu selection updated!")
}
```

Then, I hook up the two menu items to this IBAction function like this:

[image]

Build was successful, at runtime, upon click on the button, the app crashed, and throws the following exception:

> Assertion failure in -[UIMenu establishInitialDefaultSingleSelection], UIMenu.m:535
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Menu does not have a valid element for default selection'

Why do I this exception? What needs to be fixed here?

Answer (score 8):

You need to add menu items to the Pop Up Button like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var popUpButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupPopUpButton()
}

func setupPopUpButton() {
    let popUpButtonClosure = { (action: UIAction) in
        print("Pop-up action")
    }
            
    popUpButton.menu = UIMenu(children: [
        UIAction(title: "First Entry", handler: popUpButtonClosure),
        UIAction(title: "Second Entry", handler: popUpButtonClosure)
    ])
    popUpButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
}
```

Comment: This example is for the "just code" version. Have you tried out the xib version? "Build interfaces with style" https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10196/?time=602

Answer (score 2):

All menu items must be connected to an `@IBAction` and the `Pop Up Button` must have the following config items selected in the Attributes Inspector:

`Selection as Primary Action`

`Shows as Primary Action`

Comment: This can be done done completely in interface builder, but it is tricky because you can't connect a menu item to IBAction. Instead, you have to ctrl+drag the menu item to first responder and selection the function to connect to there.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an action in code:

```swift
@IBAction func menuAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
}
```

2. Drag each menu to the First Responder:

[image]

3. Select your action

[image]

4. Repeat for each action (no option currently to add tag to menu item)

Comment: Your solution is missing the type of the sender and does not demonstrate how to get the selected item from the menu.

Comment: Set sender as UICommand to get the selected option using sender.title
@IBAction func menuAction(_ sender: UICommand) {

}